# Powershell Script to find a specific file type in specific subfolders of a directory

Tags: powershell

I have a directory with several subfolders in it. I specifically want to search for the directory for a set of subfolders that begin with the combination "SS". Once it finds those specific subfolders, I want to run a batch file on those folders and also delete files of specific file type.

I've got the search for the specific subfolders to work using gci and -Recurse using the following code:

```
$BaseDir = "P:\Directory1\"
$FolderName = "SS"
Get-ChildItem $BaseDir -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Name.StartsWith($FolderName)}
```

This finds the correct subfolders, but I'm lost on how after I've gotten these results to run the batch file on them and delete the files with the specific file type. I've tried using foreach and ForEach-Object, but it's not giving any results. I've searched and can't seem to find a solution for this.

Comment: Pipe to a `Foreach-Object`  (`%` alias) loop. Also, if you're on PSv3 you can specify `-Directory` for just folders and use the `-Filter` parameter instead: `gci $basedir -filter 'ss*' -directory -recurse | % { & 'C:\my.bat' $_.FullName; if ($_.Extension -match '.txt|.pdf') { $_ | Remove-Item -WhatIf }`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use -Include, but it's picky about the path handed to it.

```
get-childitem( join-path $directory "*") -Include *.txt,*.pdf
```

The -Include option needs the path to have that trailing * wildcard on it, and **WILL NOT** work without it.

join-path is also the OS-safe way to create a path without using a directory delimiter that might not work if you're running the code on a non-Windows host.